# send NSNotificationCenter notification when phone switches off

Tags: ios, logout, nsnotificationcenter, appdelegate, nsnotifications

I would need to post a notification through NSNotificationCenter immediately before the app gets closed when the user switches the phone off. Currently I'm sending the notification in the `applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application` method inside my app delegate. Unfortunately,the notification doesn't look like working because the observer code doesn't get executed. Is there any other way to accomplish this task?

Comment: My first guess is no, when the user turns off there phone all apps just get removed from memory, just like when an user kills the app.

Comment: During the debug session,if I switch the phone off applicationWillTerminate: gets called and I can executed some code. The point is that it looks like the notification is fired,but not received. To be more precise I need one of the View Controllers to run a segue,thing I cannot do in the AppDelegate.

Comment: @Claus Yeah, it doesn't quite make sense to run a segue upon `applicationWillTerminate`. I assume you want to do that because you have some logic buried in that destination view controller? You will probably have to refactor your code, pull the salient parts of that out of that view controller, and put it in some object that you can invoke from either the view controller or `applicationWillTerminate`. Without more details about why precisely you want to do that segue and what you're doing in that destination, we probably can't help you more.

Comment: you are probably right,I wanted just to run a transition using a segue to visually  inform the user about the logout (Does it make sense?). I probably need a refactor.